# How can I generate all possible strings in a defined character set?

Tags: python

Im trying to use python to define a character set then generate all the possible strings that are the in character set.

I was thinking of first setting the character set as a variable then using for loops to generate the possible strings like this:

```
charSet = [a-zA-Z0-9]
for a in charSet:
      print (a)
for b in charSet:
      print (b)
```

But i keep getting this error message
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Is that how you actually initialized the charSet?

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9]` interprets as a list of single element, which is the result of the mathematical operation `a - zA - Z0 - 9` and your variables `a`, `zA` and `Z0` do not exist.

Comment: @eumiro - post as answer not comment

Comment: Yeah, im only looking at how to do this at the moment but not getting anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get your charSet definition problem resolved, look at itertools.product:

```
from itertools import product
import string

charSet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
for wordchars in product(charSet, repeat=4):
    print ''.join(wordchars)
```

Comment: thanks this is working well but the output is in this format:
('9', 'V')
('9', 'W')
('9', 'X')
('9', 'Y')
('9', 'Z') how can i get it output with just the characters, none of the brackets and stuff

Comment: So you have found that product will yield a succession of tuples, containing the combinations of characters. If you look again at the example I posted, I don't just print the returned tuple, I pass the tuple as an argument to `''.join` - this merges the characters of the tuple into a single string, without the parens, commas, etc.

Comment: when i do that i get this error message  `File "<module1>", line 6
    print ''.join(wordchars)
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` where the arrow points to the ''

Comment: figured it out. the ''.join needed to go inside the brackets so the last line looks like this print (''.join(wordchars)). many thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

There is no builtin syntax similar to what you are looking for, however there are some predefined strings that contain the letters you need:

```
import string
charSet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
```

For a more general solution you could try this function:

```
def getCharactersFromCharSet(charSet):
    import re
    chars = []
    for c in re.findall('.-.|.', charSet):
        if len(c) == 1:
            chars.append(c)
        else:
            for i in range(ord(c[0]), ord(c[2]) + 1):
                chars.append(chr(i))
    return ''.join(chars)

print getCharactersFromCharSet('a-zA-Z0-9')
```

Comment: Thanks this made the character set i wanted